# How to map from a list to a flat object in automapper .net

Tags: c#, .net, mapping, automapper

I have a complex object that contains a list of products.

```cs
public class Container
{
    public List<Product> Products;
}

public class Product
{
    public string Name;
    public string Colour;
}
    
public class NewClass
{
    public string Name1;
    public string Colour1;
    public string Name2;
    public string Colour2;
    public string Name3;
    public string Colour3;
}
```

I want to map the container class to the new class.
I never will have more then 3 products but when I map it with automapper I get out of range exception because I don’t know if the list will contain 1,2 or 3 products.

```
cfg.CreateMap< Container, NewClass>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Name1, 
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Product[0].name)cfg.CreateMap< Container, NewClass().ForMember(d => d.Name2, 
       opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Product[1].name)cfg.CreateMap< Container, NewClass>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Name3, 
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Product[2].name)
    );
```

Any help obviously the code is an example but essentially I have to map from a list to a flat object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to call `CreateMap` multiple times for the same source/destination objects, you can simply chain `ForMember` calls.

Instead of accessing the specified index directly you can use the method `ElementAtOrDefault` which will return the element at the specified index **or null if index is out of range**.

So you can do this:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Container, NewClass>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Products.ElementAtOrDefault(0).Name))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name2, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Products.ElementAtOrDefault(1).Name))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name3, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Products.ElementAtOrDefault(2).Name));
```